# Canvas Control Editing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need to create a control that would allow a user to manipulate (reposition, rotate) shapes (widgets?) inside a canvas control.  The shapes can vary: triangle, square, even geometric paths and could potentially have thousands of them inside the canvas.

The shapes' attributes are bound to strongly-typed classes that indicate positioning, angle of rotation, etc.

My current thought is:

1. Each widget shape is its own control (the behavior varies for each shape), though a template can be applied to vary the presentation.  This would also allow me to vary manipulation logic depending on the valid operations on the shape.
2. The controls are assigned to a canvas control (which itself has an image for a background) that would allow absolute positioning.
3. I'm assuming the parent of the control will always be a canvas (for bounds checking).

Am I on the right track or way off?  Are there similar samples out there (I tried looking, but maybe not enough).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If there's any chance to have item count ranging in thousands - I'd recommend using DirectX or Direct2D. You can still use C# if you use SharpDX or Win2D but XAML doesn't have the performance to move so many elements around.

Comment: That being said, if you don't have thousands of items, XAML should be fine. Right?

Comment: Sure and of course there might be optimizations to even get your thousands working fairly smoothly if only you don't move them all at the same time.

Comment: I may be in luck as manipulation only happens to one shape at a time. There's no need to move them all at the same time. (Also because I don't have DirectX experience, I'd love to stick with XAML).  Are there any similar samples out there that I can use to jumpstart?

Comment: The high edge case is about 3000 shapes and that rarely (but does) happen.  99% of the time it's less than 100.

Comment: Are all 3000 going to be on screen at the same time? Maybe some virtualization could help here?

Comment: When zoomed out, all of them will be on the screen, probably not editable though (they would be too small).

Comment: You could use virtualization up to some point where you'd just show a rendered image of all of them.

Comment: When Windows 10 comes out there will be a mechanism to mark UI elements so they are not introduced to the visual tree at all until you need them. This will help initial performance of your app, of course, but once you get all 3k items revealed, as long as you translate and scale the container they are in and not the indiv. elements you should still be okay. Things like this need to be tested to know for sure.